# How to determine the type of non-object generics?

Tags: delphi, generics

Obviously the following code will not work:

```
....
property value: T read FTheValue;
....
function TDefiniteValue<T>.toString: string;
begin
  Result:= ' definitly ';
  if (value is TObject) then Result:= Result + TObject(value).ToString
  else if (value is integer) then Result:= Result + IntToStr(integer(value));
  //                ^^^^^^^
  //                +++++++-- integer is not an object
end;
```

How do I compare the types of non-objects?

Here's a SSCCE

```
Program Maybe; 

interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections, System.SysUtils;

type    
  TDefiniteValue<T> = class(TEnumerable<T>)
  strict private
    FTheValue: T;
  strict protected
    function toString: string; override;
    property value: T read FTheValue;
  end;

implementation

function TDefiniteValue<T>.toString: string;
begin
  Result:= ' definitly ';
  if (value is TObject) then Result:= Result + TObject(value).ToString
  else if (value is integer) then Result:= Result + IntToStr(integer(value));
  //                ^^^^^^^
  //                +++++++-- integer is not an object.
end;

begin
end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `System.Rtti.TValue`:

```
function TDefiniteValue<T>.ToString: string;
var
  v: TValue;
begin
  v := TValue.From<T>(FTheValue);
  Result:= ' definitly ' + v.ToString;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

DSharp has a unit just that purpose, here's the link:

https://code.google.com/p/delphisorcery/source/browse/trunk/Source/Core/DSharp.Core.Reflection.pas

It contains a list of class helpers for the `Rtti`. Which allows you to interrogate your objects.

The relevant section is here:

```
TValue = Rtti.TValue;

{$REGION 'Documentation'}
/// <summary>
/// Extends <see cref="Rtti.TValue">TValue</see> for easier RTTI use.
/// </summary>
{$ENDREGION}
TValueHelper = record helper for TValue
private
function GetRttiType: TRttiType;
class function FromFloat(ATypeInfo: PTypeInfo; AValue: Extended): TValue; static;
public
function IsFloat: Boolean;
function IsNumeric: Boolean;
function IsPointer: Boolean;
function IsString: Boolean;

function IsInstance: Boolean;
function IsInterface: Boolean;

// conversion for almost all standard types
function TryConvert(ATypeInfo: PTypeInfo; out AResult: TValue): Boolean; overload;
function TryConvert<T>(out AResult: TValue): Boolean; overload;

function AsByte: Byte;
function AsCardinal: Cardinal;
....
```